# Python extract values in JSON array to form a new key-value pair

Tags: python, json

Given an array of JSON objects as:

```
arr=[{"id": "abc", "value": "123"}, {"id": "xyz", "value": "456"}]
```

I would like to output a single JSON object like:

```
new_arr={"abc":123,"xyz":456}
```

Currently I can extract the elements like `arr[0]['id']` but I am wondering what's the one-liner or better way to form the output.

Comment: `arr` is a list of dictionaries. Describe in your own words what you need to do to each element of `arr` to get the key-value pairs you want for your `new_arr` dict (`new_arr` is a horrible name for a dict, btw). Then translate that description into a program. Don't look for one-liners to begin with -- once you've figured out how to do it in multiple lines, you can condense it down to one line if it makes sense

Comment: Breaking this down into smaller steps, you'd need to 1. iterate over all elements (`e`) in your list `arr`. 2. Each `e` is a `dict`. `e["id"]` tells you the key. `e["value"]` tells you the value. 3. You want to convert `e["value"]` to an integer 4. Assign that converted value to that key of your output dictionary `new_arr`. Which of these steps are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-liner to extract the ids and values would be like this:

```
new_arr = {item['id']: int(item['value']) for item in arr}
```

as the arr object contains the value as a `str` you need to convert it to an `int()`. The rest of the one line similar to a list comprehension with dict as the base element to add to, thereby being a dict comprehension. Though this assumes that all dicts have a id and value combination (which is unknown from your data and am assuming that they always have an id and value)

Comment: In that case, you should edit to add what it's actually called.  Clearer language would be "The `{x: y for ...}` construct is called a _dict_ comprehension, which is similar to a list comprehension but creates a dictionary"

Answer (score 0):

One alternative, showing the versatility of [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

arr = [{"id": "abc", "value": "123"}, {"id": "xyz", "value": "456"}]

# itemgetter creates a function to extract the values at id and value
pair = itemgetter("id", "value")

# use map to apply the function to each element of arr
d = dict(map(pair, arr))

# print the result
print(d)
```

**Output**

```
{'abc': '123', 'xyz': '456'}
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution can be this:

```py
new_arr = {item['id']: int(item['value']) for item in arr}
```

Or you can use `itemgetter` opertaror:

```py
new = dict(map(itemgetter("id", "value"), arr))
```

Comment: How is your answer different from the ones **already** proposed?

Answer (score 0):

Minimum code I think

```
arr = [{"id": "abc", "value": "123"}, {"id": "xyz", "value": "456"}]
json = {item['id']: item['value'] for item in arr}
print(json)
```

result:

```
{'abc': '123', 'xyz': '456'}
```